# Is $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\delta_n=0$ for $\{\delta_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset(0,1)$ decreasing to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> Is $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\delta_n=0$ for $\{\delta_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset(0,1)$ decreasing to $0$?

I used the following approach: Let $g(n)=\Pi_{i=1}^n\delta_i$. We know that $g(n)$ is strictly decreasing in $n$ given $\delta_i\in(0,1)$. We also know that the product of any number of positive reals is positive. Hence $\{g(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence bounded below by $0$. Such s sequence converges to $\inf \{g_n\}=0.$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Just because it's strictly decreasing and bounded below by $0$ does not mean $0$ is in the infimum. $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}$ also has that property but its infimum is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Good point.

Comment: You can't prove the product is $0$ because it may not be. If for example $\delta_n=1-1/n^2$ then $\prod \delta_n>0$.

Comment: Remember logarithms have the property that they turn products into sums.  If we apply logarithms here, you are stating $\sum b_n$ diverges to $-\infty$ if $b_n<0$.  This is false, as shown by the existence of absolutely convergent series.

Comment: I put more structure on it, namely that deltas are strictly decreasing sequence getting closer to 0. This would be enough for the product to converge to 0, right?

Comment: Actually I think non-increasing deltas would be enough. Right?

Comment: I think you could get away with $\delta_i$ that stay away from $0$, i.e. $\delta_i < 1-\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ and all $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\delta_i$ are decreasing, then $\delta_i < r$ for some $0 < r < 1$ and all $i$, thus

$$ 0 \le \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \delta_i \le \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} r = \lim_{n\to\infty}r^n \le 0.$$

By squeeze theorem, the product is zero. In fact, you don't need that they're decreasing at all, just that they stay away from $1$ and the above works. This is of course a sufficient condition, but infinite series and products can have extremely bizarre behavior. I doubt there's a good way to further classify this to catch those products whose $\delta_i$ do not stay away from $1$ (some work, some don't).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, your proof has a gap. And it is also needlessly complicated.

You assume that $(\delta_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset(0,1)$ strictly decreases to $0$. In particular,

$$\delta_1\in (0,1), \quad \delta_n\in (0,\delta_1] \; \forall n\ge 1,$$

which yields

$$g(N)=\prod_{n=1}^N\delta_n\le \delta_1^N\xrightarrow{N\to\infty} 0.$$